# Wordpress - page_link filter

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

I'm trying to change default pages post type permalink, I'd like to add a '.php' to its end for example: `home_url() . post_name . '.php'`

I can't use WordPress permalinks page because I'm using it already like this: `/%category%/%postname%.php` and this doesn't affect the default pages post type.

**So I did it like follows:**

```
function wp_pages_permalink( $permalink, $post_id ) {
    if ( empty( $post_id ) ) return $permalink;

    $post = get_post( $post_id );

    return home_url( $post->post_name . '.php'  );
}

add_filter( 'page_link', 'wp_pages_permalink', 10, 2 );
```

However I get a 404 when I try to visit the page, **and I have already flushed the rewrite rules by visiting the permalinks page**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suspected, this needed a rewrite rule.. I don't know why post_link filter didn't need a rewrite rule added..

```
function ba_rewrite() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^([^/]*)?.php', 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]', 'top');
}

add_action( 'init', 'ba_rewrite' );
```

Answer (score 0):

So you're just changing the output of the link
with the address you would want 
but the actual page doesn't get changed;

I believe you should target the $permalink_structure instead of just $permalink,
try to use something like:

```
function wp_pages_permalink( $permalink_structure, $post_id ) {
    if ( empty( $post_id ) ) return $permalink_structure ;

    $post = get_post( $post_id );

    return ( $permalink_structure . '.php'  );
}

add_filter( 'page_link', 'wp_pages_permalink', 10, 2 );
```

I made the changes based on your code so you may need to work on it...

Anyway if you want to checkout what happens with permalinks take a look at the documentation ([WP_rewrite class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite))

Comment: So, what did you do to my code? You changed a variable name? It's supposed to work now? I don't think so.

Comment: no, I don't/can't know if the code works in your project.. but looking at the WP_rewrite class I saw that the $permalink_structure method is where the permalink is made, probably it's not good pratice to access it directly...

Answer (score -4):

Try to do these steps:

1. add the extension in permalinks (settings->permalinks) 
   -> I use this format: `/%post_id%/%postname%.php`
2. save it
3. in your wordpress files go to wp-includes -> rewrite.php and on the line 1148 replace this line of code

   $this->page_structure = $this->root . '%pagename%';

with this one

```
$this->page_structure = $this->root . '%pagename%.php';
```

4. save it and try now.

Comment: No, of course I will not replace a line in the wp-includes folder.

Comment: I answered my question already http://stackoverflow.com/a/27439590/2101942 Never try to edit a file outside the wp-content folder.